# jquery sortable - moving items between lists works but doesn't get propagated

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two lists like that:

```
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="sortable2_1">Martin</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="sortable2_3">Mirek</li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="sortable1_2">Karel</li>
</ul>
```

and I have this jquery code:

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable0" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        /**/update : function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",  
                url: "somescript.php",  
                data: 
                {
                data:$("#sortable1").sortable('serialize')+'&'+$("#sortable2").sortable('serialize')
                }, 
                timeout: 50000,
                async: true,
                cache: false
            });
        }/**/
    }).disableSelection();
```

My problem is that when its send to script, I get two arrays, sortable1 and sortable2, but if I move item from one to other, it will not hapen in that script. I can have sortable2 with order 1,3 or 3,1 but never 1,2,3 because item number 2 will not be added to that list (but it is added and is there in browser, that change just doen't get propagated to ajaxcall/saving script)

**EDIT**: I think that it might have something to do with ID value of LI elements, But I don't know how to do it differently - if I have those IDs as sortable_1 (instead of sortable2_1), they make one big list after serialization.

Comment: If I understand you question, you want to drag items from sortable1 to sortable2 (drag items from list 1 to list 2)? and then save the changes via ajax?

Comment: yes, but what is sent is just order, but I don't get those list changes of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there is something weird when you drag items across lists.

When I faced this problem, I solved it bij copying the item and deleting the old one... I know this helped in my case.

```
    //create list items draggagble
    $(".draggableItem").draggable({
        revert: true  //an effect if dropped outside drop zone
    });

    //create lists droppable
    $("ul").sortable({
        cursor: 'pointer'
    }).droppable({
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            drop: function(ev, ui) {
                //copy list item
                var $li = $('<li>').html(ui.draggable.html()).addClass($(ui.draggable).attr("class")).attr("rel", $(ui.draggable).attr("rel"));
                $li.draggable({revert: true});
                $li.appendTo(this);
                //delete old list item
                $(ui.draggable).remove();
                //execute ajax call

                $.ajax({
                    type: ***,
                    url: ***,
                    data: { *** }
                }).done(function() {
                    ***
                });
            }
    });
```

I don't know this is the answer you were looking for, but I hope it helps

Comment: Thx, but I will try that as a last resort solution - it might work, but I believe that there is MUCH cleaner way.